# Does AssertFailedException have any special treatment in unit-tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, exception

I was wondering if there is anything special about the `AssertFailedException`?

Is it required to be thrown for failed unit-tests or is it ok to throw any exception?

Would something not work if I throw any other exception or would the test engine behave in any different way?

I mean, is the `AssertFailedException` treated differently then other exceptions?

Comment: Very nice, downvoting without any comment...

Answer (score 4):

OK, the answer is YES.

I did some tests and found out that the `AssertFailedException` is treated differently and it's quite evil.

The `AssertFailedException` hides the entire stack-trace and all messages from inner exceptions and outputs only it's own messasge. It doesn't matter if I set the innter exception or not. It won't be displayed.

This is the strck trace that you see:

> Exception of type 'UnitTestDemo.MyException' was thrown.    at
>   UnitTestDemo.Foo(String bar) in C:[...]\Validations.cs:line 41    at
>   UnitTestDemo.IsNullOrEmpty() in C:[...]\ValidationTests.cs:line 29

And this is what you get when you throw a custom exception with an inner one:

> Test method UnitTestDemo.IsNullOrEmptyPasses threw exception: 
>   UnitTestDemo.ValidationException: Exception of type
>   'UnitTestDemo.ValidationException' was thrown but none has been
>   expected. ---> UnitTestDemo.ValidationException: 'bar' must be null or
>   empty.
>
> at UnitTestDemo.Validation'1.Throw[TException](Func'2 getMessage) in C:[...]\ValidationHelper.cs:line 25    at
>   UnitTestDemo.IsNullOrEmpty(ValidationContext'1 context, Func'2
>   getMessage) in C:[...]\Validations.cs:line 42    at
>   UnitTestDemo.ValidationTests.<>c.b__2_0() in
>   C:[...]\ValidationTests.cs:line 29    at
>   UnitTestDemo.DoesNotThrow(ValidationContext`1 context) in
>   C:[...]\Validations.cs:line 36  --- End of inner exception stack
>   trace ---
>     at UnitTestDemo.DoesNotThrow(ValidationContext'1 context) in C:[...]\Validations.cs:line 40    at
>   UnitTestDemo.IsNullOrEmptyPasses() in C:[...]\ValidationTests.cs:line
>   29

You see not only the message from the test but also from inner exceptions and the complete stack trace.

Comment: @StevieV this might be interesting for you ;-)

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, and yes it is very interesting to me as a user of the MS testing framework. I am up-voting this, thank you.

Comment: Only, I wouldn't exactly say it's quite evil. I'll tell you where I use it all of the time, when I'm writing an API for a piece of instrumentation/equipment. Say the software works, but by some quirk in the equipment, the equipment doesn't work because the *way* I am controlling it (maybe I sent some bad command). Say I expect some response from the device and get a different one, I know that the equipment did what it thought it was supposed to do, but by my own fault in not controlling the equipment correctly it gave me the wrong response, I do `Assert.Fail()` and admit a blatant failure.

Comment: Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @StevieV I used to use `Assert.Fail()` for the exact same reason ;-)

Comment: And what is it that you do now, instead? Do you recommend some different technique?

Comment: @StevieV I use my own [Validation Extensions v2 (Code Review)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131959/validation-extensions-v2) in the production code as well as a replacement for the assert.

Comment: Do you have some open source version of it somewhere?

Comment: @StevieV I have one but it's currently not up-to-date because I still need to make a few adjustments. I'll let you know when I've uploaded it.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @StevieV I've updated my github. There is a link to it in my profile. The project where you find the validation extensions is the SmartUtilities repository.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that *yes* this type of exception is special, but only in that it happens to be the type of exception thrown when the following code is encountered:

```
Assert.Fail();
```

No this is definitely not required, but whenever I am using MSTest this is the type of exception that I throw whenever I need to *blatantly* indicate to the Test-Explorer that my test has failed.

No, everything would still work. However, keep in mind that whenever you throw an exception (at least in the case of Visual-Studio's MSTest) your test will indeed fail. Actually, this is how you will test your code for some of the problems/bugs it may have. Sometimes when my tests fail it was because my code is throwing an exception (and fails), allowing me to track down and fix my bug.

Please see the documentation over at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assertfailedexception.aspx). As you can see this type of exception just inherits the normal `System.Exception` and therefore cannot be expected to behave any differently than any other kind of exception.

Comment: This sounds good. I'm creating a few custom validations/assertions that I'd like to reuse for other purposes and I don't want to include the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` namespace if it's not necessary. I thought maybe VS somewhere in its unit test engine has a `catch(AssertFailedException)` and does some magic when it occurs.

Comment: @t3chb0t Good to hear. Yeah, when you throw an exception (and are using MSTest in Visual Studio) you will get a test-failure.

Comment: I see you've been also downvoted and no one left a comment. I really dislike such people.

Comment: @t3chb0t I appreciate you saying that. However, I will have to admit to being guilty of down-voting without leaving a comment.